# Avoiding Nil errors from a form parameter when using a default value for a text_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

If below I'm using either a default session value or (with priority) a form parameter, is there a way to write the code below to avoid a nil error?

```
<%= f.text_field :deliver_to_addr, :size => 100, :maxlength => 100, :value => params[:request][:delivery_to_address] || session[:address]  %>
```

I worked around the problem by putting a logic block in the controller to come out with a single variable to hold what should be selected (below), but is there a simple way to get around this problem so I don't need a block of code every time I need to use a default value (session[:address] in this case)?

```
    if !params[:request].blank?
      if !params[:request][:delivery_to_address].blank?
        @delivery_addr_to_select = params[:request][:delivery_to_address]
      else
        @delivery_addr_to_select = session[:address]
      end
    else
      @delivery_addr_to_select = session[:address]
    end

<%= f.text_field :deliver_to_addr, :size => 100, :maxlength => 100, :value => @delivery_addr_to_select %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the build in `try`-method:

```
@delivery_addr_to_select = params[:request].try(:[], :delivery_to_address) || session[:address]
```

This will try to invoke the `[]` hash method with `:delivery_to_address` if the result is `nil` it will take the `session[:address]`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the gem [andand](https://github.com/raganwald/andand) to help shorten the logic to

```
@delivery_addr_to_select = params[:request].andand[:delivery_to_address] || session[:address]
```

This works whether or not `:request` is present because `andand` will only invoke `:delivery_to_address` if `params[:request]` is not nil.